# Error: list has no add() attribute?

Tags: python

I'm trying to delete duplicate entries from data that look like this:

```
name    phone   email   website
Diane Grant Albrecht M.S.           
Lannister G. Cersei M.A.T., CEP 111-222-3333    cersei@got.com  www.got.com
Argle D. Bargle Ed.M.           
Sam D. Man Ed.M.    000-000-1111    dman123@gmail.com   www.daManWithThePlan.com
Sam D. Man Ed.M.            
Sam D. Man Ed.M.    111-222-333     dman123@gmail.com   www.daManWithThePlan.com
D G Bamf M.S.           
Amy Tramy Lamy Ph.D.
```

So that it looks like this:

```
name    phone   email   website
Diane Grant Albrecht M.S.           
Lannister G. Cersei M.A.T., CEP 111-222-3333    cersei@got.com  www.got.com
Argle D. Bargle Ed.M.           
Sam D. Man Ed.M.    000-000-1111, 111-222-333   dman123@gmail.com   www.daManWithThePlan.com
D G Bamf M.S.           
Amy Tramy Lamy Ph.D.
```

Here's my code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv
import re

input = open('ieca_first_col_fake_text.txt', 'rU')

# default to empty set for phone, email, website, area, degrees
extracted_data = defaultdict(lambda: [set(), set(), set()])

for row in input:
    for index, value in enumerate(row):    
        name = row[0]
        data = extracted_data[name].add(row)

for row in data: print row
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'add'
logout
```

UPDATE:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv
import re

input = open('ieca_first_col_fake_text.txt', 'rU')
input_r = csv.reader(input, delimiter = '\t')

# default to empty set for phone, email, website, area, degrees
extracted_data = defaultdict(lambda: [set(), set(), set()])

data = []

# Index on the name and then for that name add the rest of the information. 
for row in input_r:

    data_set = extracted_data[row[0]]
    for index, value in enumerate(row[1:]):
        data_set[index].add(value)

print data_set
```

output:

```
[set(['']), set(['']), set([''])]
logout
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`extracted_data` values are **lists** of 3 sets each:

```
extracted_data = defaultdict(lambda: [set(), set(), set()])
```

You need to read the previous answer more closely and pick the right set to call `.add()` on.

The previous answer loops over 4 elements in your input line, uses the first element to find the list of sets, and adds each of the other 3 elements to those sets:

```
for index, value in enumerate(split(entry)):
    if index == 0:
        data_set = extracted_data[name]
    elif value:
        data_set[index - 1].add(value)
```

Personally, I'd use:

```
entry = entry.split()  # split on whitespace
for value, dset in zip(entry[1:], extracted_data[entry[0]]):
    dset.add(value)
```

to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Should I split the row if it's tab separated?

Comment: @goldisfine: It isn't, the previous answerer did not know what format you used. The comment above it reads *Assume split() returns ...*.

Comment: so should I call .split('/t')? Sorry for being slow here. But I don't want to split on spaces because then I split up the name.

Comment: No, `str.split()` with no arguments splits on variable width whitespace, and strips the line for you too. Much better.

Comment: Does that mean it splits on the largest whitespace separation, preferring to split on tabs rather than on spaces, therefore avoiding the problem of splitting up first, middle, and last names rather than name, phone, email?

Comment: Ah, no, indeed, in that case use `line.strip().split('\t')`, or better still, use the `csv` module and configure that to use `\t` as the delimiter.

Comment: What does 'extracted_data' mean?

Comment: It's the `defaultdict` defined in the other answer. `extracted_data = defaultdict(lambda: [set(), set(), set()])`. You posted that in you own question here..

Comment: Right, okay, so 'extracted_data' is the defaultdict and entry[0] would be the name, so by passing 'entry[0]' to the default dict, am I passing it the column of names and therefore feeding it a list of indices?

Comment: Yes, `entry[0]` is presumed to be the name, and `defaultdict[name]` returns a list of 3 sets (because that is what the `lambda` callable creates if no such key was found).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33101/discussion-between-goldisfine-and-martijn-pieters)

Comment: Personally, I'd use the same thing as well, except that other answer was arrived at evolutionarily, so the way it was is actually an improvement on what it had been previously, but I missed the opportunity for your optimization because I was already thinking in a different pattern.  :)  +1  You could also use a `while entry: entry.pop()` loop with a counter instead of slicing and enumerating.

Comment: Or your even better improvement you edited in right as I submitted my comment.  :)

Comment: And one step further, use `itertools.izip` so you don't chew memory.

Comment: For 3 sets that is really overkill.

Comment: Fair point.  Though since this is a nested loop, you'll be creating potentially lots and lots of zipped lists with duplicated references to `dset`s and you can't really be sure when these things will be cleaned up.

Comment: Yes you can be sure that things will be cleaned up.

Comment: You can be sure that they will, but not when.  But we're picking nits that are probably inconsequential in this case anyway.  :)

Comment: You are rebinding local loop variables. We rapidly increase and decrease reference counts. Only `entry` doesn't have references outside of the loop, so that's the *only* value that might run the risk of not being cleaned up. There is **no risk** here that values are alive too long.

Comment: The rest of the values we *want* to retain. That's why we are adding them to a set..